# segmentation fault creating pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm having a segmentation fault problem with a networking program using threads to deal with each new connection.

MAX_PEERS is defined above as 10.

```
...
int iret[MAX_PEERS];
pthread_t thread[MAX_PEERS];


(void) signal(SIGCHLD, reaper);
printf("before while\n");
int i = 0;
while(1) {
    if(i>MAX_PEERS-1){break;}
    client_len = sizeof(client);
    new_sd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &client_len);
    if(new_sd < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't accept client \n");
    exit(1);
  }
    printf("before thread\n");
    iret[i] = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connection, (void*) new_sd);
    if(iret != 0){
        printf("thread[%d] not generated!\n", i);
    }
    i++;
    printf("end of while\n");
}
....
```

and the function "connection" beggins as follows

```
void *connection(void *sdd)
{
    int sd =* (int *) sdd; 
...
```

When the client tries to connect to the server I get a segmentation fault.

```
> ./server 20011                  
before while
before accept
after accept
before thread
./server: zsh: segmentation fault  ./server 20011
>
```

It prints "before accept" before the client connects, and after the client connects it prints the rest.

Am I creating the threads correctly? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: You should pass `&new_sd` as arg to `pthread_create`

Comment: this line: if(i>MAX_PEERS-1){break;} moves execution to the line: printf("before thread\n");  and the very next line is using that 'i' value as an index into the array of '&thread[i],' which results in undefined behaviour, in this case, with a seg fault event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accept() returns an integer, so `new_sd` must be an integer. When you create a new thread you cast `new_sd` to a void pointer. But when you get that pointer in the function, instead of casting back to int you cast it to a pointer to int and dereference it, which causes the seg fault.

Instead of using possibly incorrect casting, rather pass an integer. Assuming that `new_sd` will go out of scope, allocate space for an integer and pass it to your thread.

```
int* new_sdp = malloc( sizeof( *new_sdp )) ;
*new_sdp = new_sd ;

iret[i] = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, connection, new_sdp);
```

and in the thread:

```
void *connection(void *sdd)
{
    int sd = *(int *)sdd;
```